# Database connection with JDBC using Ucanaccess no output

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I try to create a connection between JDBC and MS Access.

I follow the instruction [as per this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc). I am using IntelliJ Idea. Here I am sharing some snaps to describe my problem.

[image]

This is the code that I write down to make a connection with Database `Database2`. But as you can see there is no error neither any output. Now I am sharing the table structure and content on the table.

[image]

2nd picture is [image]

My code is:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Connection_sample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D://tutorial/Database2.accdb");
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();
        s.executeQuery("select * from Student");
        ResultSet rset = s.getResultSet();

        while (rset.next()) {
            System.out.println(rset.getInt(1)+""+rset.getInt(2));
        }
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Can anyone help me to find the error?

Comment: Please don't post images of code, but post code as text. Possibly your problem is the result of using `getResultSet()` instead of using the result set returned by `executeQuery()`. You should only use `getResultSet()` in combination with `execute()`.

Comment: I change it like this `ResultSet rset= s.executeQuery("select * from Student"); ` and it is working. Thanks a lot. Could you please explain, why this type of change neede?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the result of using `getResultSet()` instead of using the result set returned by `executeQuery()`. You should only use `getResultSet()` in combination with `execute()`.

A result set should only be obtained once, and it was already returned from `executeQuery` (which you ignored). When you called `getResultSet`, you - apparently - got an empty one (which technically violates the contract).